# Sheaves on a Simplicial Complex

Tags: sheaf-theory, simplicial-complex

I came across a video the other day which discussed practical applications of sheaves. However, rather than defining a sheaf on the open sets of a traditional topological space, the lecturer outlined how you would define them on a simplicial complex, assigning sections to each n-simplex with the restriction maps commuting between across the faces to higher dimensional simplices.

It was nice to have a simple "finite" presentation of a sheaf to get an idea for 
what the gluing condition says and when it might fail.

Because the lecture was focused on applications, no formal definition was given. I was wondering if this kind of construction is common, and what the formal definition would look like. Also, I would like to know if there are any written resources (papers, textbooks, articles) that discuss it.

The closest I was able to find on my own is that in category theory, there is a notion of a simplicial sheaf, which is defined on a simplicial set. I have a very vague understanding of simplicial sets, and I'm wondering if perhaps sheaves on a simplicial complex are a special case of these.

Comment: out of curiosity, can you give a link to the video?

Comment: It's Michael Robinson's lecture on Sheaves in Data Analytics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1Wu8kTngoE&list=PLSekr_gm4hWLvFtJX0WUueVO65uhvBPrA&index=1

Comment: Like a sheaf takes values in $\text{Set}$, a simplicial sheaf takes values in simplicial sets. What your lecturer was talking about was a sheaf (set-valued) defined on a simplicial set, which amounts to regarding the simplicial set as a topological space (via it's geometric realization). Those are two very different things, so don't get confused here.